# Percentage Calculation Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate score that has 5 sections( minimum of 3 questions per sections). Among these some can be N/A. I need to calculate in such a way that the first 4 parts should be (Total Yes answers) /  (total Yes+NO questions)  * 10 and the 5th part should be multiplied by 60. Finally I need to sum all 5 parts to get a final score .

**My Solution : (first 4 parts)**

```
=IFERROR((COUNTIF(D70:D72,"Yes")/SUM(COUNTIF(D70:D72,"Yes"),(COUNTIF(D70:D72,"No"))))*10,"N/A")
```

The above formula continues for other 3 sections with different range values

**5th part :**

```
=IFERROR((COUNTIF(D70:D72,"Yes")/SUM(COUNTIF(D70:D72,"Yes"),(COUNTIF(D70:D72,"No"))))*60,"N/A")
```

**Final Score :**

```
=AGGREGATE(9,6,(G30,G42,G52,G64,G73))/100
```

I tested my formula having one section has **N/A** and other has **YES**. This gives me a result of 90% rather than 100%

My question is what if one of the parts is completely n/a. then how I should ignore the n/a section and still get 100%

Comment: Thanks Chrismas007 for the edit ! I am new to this site and getting used to !

Comment: If one of the 10 questions is N/A, what are the weightings for the other questions?

Comment: If only one question is n/a , then the weight would be 100%. But I am not able to get 100% when 1 section(for e.g having 4 questions)  is completely n/a.

Comment: I know, but you haven't explained what behaviour you'd prefer. If one section is N/A, you have to adjust the weightings for the other sections so that the total weight is 100; would you like to do that by simply scaling them all up (so 11.1 on the other three out of ten, and 66.7 on the last, aprox.) or would you rather a different method?

Comment: You got my point ! But I am wondering how would I default that , rather than manually changing it every time when there is a N/A section

Comment: OK, I get it now. Answer coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah !It did work Finally ! Thanks a lot for your guidance !

```
 =IFERROR((SUM(G30,G42,G52,G64,G73)/SUM(IF(G30="#N/A",0,10),IF(G42="#N/A",0,10),IF(G52="#N/A",0,10),IF(G64="#N/A",0,10),IF(G73="#N/A",0,60))), "-")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your final calculation, rather than dividing by 100 you need to divide by the sum of the possible points. There will be a more elegant way to do this, but since there are only five of them:

```
=AGGREGATE(9,6,(G30,G42,G52,G64,G73))/SUM(IF(ISERROR(G30),0,10),IF(ISERROR(G42),0,10),IF(ISERROR(G52),0,10),IF(ISERROR(G64),0,10),IF(ISERROR(G73),0,60))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the above method(with one section as N/A , and rest as Yes ) unfortunately, it still shows 90% rather than 100%

Comment: Manually typing it !

Comment: That's your problem; I assumed you were getting an excel N/A, which is picked up by 'ISERROR'